# SQL STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, sql, str-to-date, error-messaging

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
INSERT into `fun` ( funner)
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(time,1,4), '%Y')) 
FROM `orig`
```

returning the warning:

> Incorrect datetime value: '1880' for function str_to_date

`time` is a varchar column in the table `orig` with the format `yyyy/mm`.

I want to extract the year section from this varchar and translate it into a year datatype using `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: Why `SUBSTRING(time,1,4)` is not enough?

Comment: @ salman A Because I am inserting the data into a column with a date/time data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using one of the [usual date and time MySQL datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html), instead of the rarely used [`YEAR` datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/year.html) : `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`.

If you want to turn your string to a `date` datatype, then :

```
STR_TO_DATE(my_column, '%Y/%m')
```

You can use the `YEAR()` function on this date, and it will return an `integer` value :

```
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(my_column, '%Y/%m'))
```

Finally : if all you want is get the year from a date stored as string, then you can directly extract it the string using `SUBSTR` :

```
SUBSTR(my_column, 1, 4)
```

This returns a string (not an integer), that MySQL will implictely convert to a number when used in numeric context.

Comment: @ GMB I must be misunderstanding the option for 'year(4)' under  the date and time section as an type? I also have TIME and YEAR in addition to DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP

Comment: @HannahGarcia : my mistake ! I updated my answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `SUBSTRING(time,1,4)` to integer:

```
SELECT CONVERT(SUBSTRING(time,1,4),UNSIGNED INTEGER) FROM orig
```

there is no need to convert it first to a date and then convert to integer.
I guess you need to return an integer value since you use the YEAR() function. 
If not a simple `SELECT SUBSTRING(time,1,4) FROM orig` will do.

Answer (score 0):

What does `time` look like?  If `year` has the data type year, then you can insert a date into the column:

```
INSERT into `clean` (year)
    SELECT DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(time, 1, 4), '-01-01')) 
    FROM `orig` ;
```

I am not a fan of the `year` data type.  You should just put the entire date into the column.